# PHP - how to build combination words with recursive?

Tags: php, recursion, combinations, combinatorics

I need build to combination words with recursive
Example:

**Input:**

```
Array {'sun','fun','beach','surf',..,n}
```

**Output:**

```
Level 1

sun
fun
beach
surf

Level 2:

sun beach
sun fun
sun surf
beach fun
beach surf
fun surf

Level 3

sun fun beach
sun fun surf
sun beach surf 
fun beach surf

Level n
.
.
.
n
```

I using Math combinatiorics, but it's proccess result too long, i have 1 hour for that.

Comment: Are your sample output accurate? Is it intentional to have the level 1 output be "sun fun beach surf" instead of "sun beach fun surf"? Is there some other logic to the interpretation that I am missing?

Comment: The actual code which does that would be helpful to see.